# Acumatica AP Electronic Payments Notification

Tags: email-attachments, acumatica

I think we are like all electronic payment users.  We want to send  notifications to our vendors who receive electronic payments from us.  Has anyone had any luck or is selling an emailable report to send to vendors after you have cut them an electronic payment?  We would even pay someone to create the report.  Customers are demanding this.  Thank

Answer (score 0):

My company [SWK Technologies](http://www.swktech.com/) sells a ACH/EFT customization that allows you to create ACH files and email remittances from the Batch Payments screen.  We just got it certified by Acumatica.  You can also email mary.abdian@swktech.com for more info.